# configure redelivery-delay-multiplier on wildfly 8

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8, hornetq

I try to configure a JMS queue with delay multiplier in `WildFly 8.2.0`, but I have an issue during `stadalone.xml` parsing when the server is started. Obviously, the parameter `<redelivery-delay-multiplier>` is not recognised.
But when I see the release note of `WildFly 8.2.0`, it's shipped with `HornetQ 2.4.5` which includes this parameter.
Any one please has an idea about this configuration and how to make the delay multiplier work on `WildFly 8`? 
Thank you

Comment: You have an issue, could you expand on that a bit? What errors or indications are you getting that what you do is wrong? Perhaps [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) your question, and include the relevant part(s) of your `standalone.xml`.